# Using Angular Elements to build micro-frontends

Tags: angular, angular-elements, micro-frontend

I've been using Angular Elements to build micro-frontends and when each micro-frontends is a completely isolated micro frontend everything works correctly.

```html
<script src="bundle-a.js"></script>
<script src="bundle-b.js"></script>
<a-component></a-component>
<b-component></b-component>
```

However, I've noticed that if the Angular Elements are nested using components from more than one micro-frontends, this introduces some UI issues that are very complex to fix

```html
<script src="bundle-a.js"></script>
<script src="bundle-b.js"></script>
<a-component>
    <b-component></b-component>
</a-component>
```

For example, nesting components in this way causes the following issues:

-Change detection needs to be triggered manually (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24061)

-Transclusion doesn't work correctly (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24536)

-Cannot create or destroy components dynamically (possibly related to the change detection issue above)

The use case for this is that  is a reusable UI component (e.g. button or data table) that is referenced by another micro-frontend.

The alternative to this is to include the common UI components as an NPM dependency in each micro-frontend. However, the disadvantage of this approach is that if the common UI components change, I then need to rebuild each consuming application.

Does anyone have any suggestions? It's important that each micro-frontend can be built and deployed independently so should be referenced as a runtime JS incude rather than as an NPM dependency.

From my research so far, it appears that Angular Elements is intended for isolated micro apps rather than a UI component library that could be shared across multiple micro-frontend.

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: The change detection issue can be fixed by including the following library:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/elements-zone-strategy

Comment: If anyone is interested in this, I was able to get this to work by making the following changes:

-Modify bootstrapping of custom elements to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/elements-zone-strategy
-Update components that use named tranclusion slots to use the slot API instead of ng-content. See https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2018/10/31/content-projection-with-slots-in-angular-elements-7.aspx

The end result is that you can have multiple microservices running (either microapps or UI component libraries) which are completely decoupled and can be build and deployed independently.